# slider not showing when slicer visual selected on power bi - icon says slicer(new)

Tags: powerbi, slider, slicers

I want to select slicer visual to show order dates and a slider to control dates. However the slider is not showing as default when slicer icon selected as it does in the tutorial I am following. It shows all the dates rendered in thier own containers as opposed to the first and last date and a slider bar. Any suggestions will  be appreciated. Thanks Alex

I have tried selecting the first and last date but can not find the option for 'between'. I have searched for a 'hide' slider. I have ensured the data type is set to DATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the "Slicer" and not "Slicer (new)".

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sam!! Sincerely... I knew it shouldn't be that hard. It had been a long day. Sincerely, Alex. Sam a job oppurtunity may depend on said report being shared. I have power bi pro access and can not seem to share the report/dashboard with someone elses email address. Please could you advise how I can grant access to another email address outside of my 'organisation' Thank you again, Alex.